# Can R.class.(an inherited class) be written?

Tags: android

It is clear that R.class contains IDs for all my android resources.

So I am trying to use a whole new inherited class as a resource similar to `R.drawable.image`. **Is it possible ?**

Comment: actualy this was my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think no.

because **R.class** is auto-generated resource files class.

Comment: then how can i b able to do that ??

Comment: You should make another class and define resources and import it.

Answer (score 0):

`R.drawable.image` is available if you put a file named image in any of the drawable folders

Comment: actually i have edited my question now so....... please reconsider my problem.....(thank you)

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: the thing is, i have taken gridview layout and  trying to show   timer inside a circle  in every grid.so how the thing will be done, i dont know thats why asking for some help. (thank you)